# BehaviorSubject next method not updating changes for another component

Tags: angular9

Hello I have developed user service, working of that user service is to share data between component that does not have relationship with them. if i am changing data from peoplecompoent it is not detected by inboxcomponent.
Here i am posnting code for my servce.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject,Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {UserModel } from '../Models/UserModel';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

public messageSubject$ : BehaviorSubject<UserModel[]> =  new BehaviorSubject(null);

public users : UserModel[]=[];



constructor() { 

for(var i =0 ;i<=6;i++){
  var user = new UserModel();
  user.userId = i.toString();
  user.userName = 'Ashok Kumar';
  user.userInterest = i.toString();
  user.isActiveInbox = false;
  user.isActiveCurrent = false;
  this.users.push(user);
}

this.messageSubject$.asObservable();
}

getUser(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
   return this.messageSubject$.asObservable();
}

  addUser(){
    var user = new UserModel();
    user.userId = '7';
    user.userName = 'Ashok Kumar';
    user.userInterest = '7';
    user.isActiveInbox = true;
    user.isActiveCurrent = true;
    this.users.push(user);
 }

 changeUser(){
    this.messageSubject$.next(this.users);
  }

activeForInbox(userId: string){
var user = this.users.find(x=> x.userId==userId);
user.isActiveInbox = true;

this.messageSubject$.next(this.users);
console.log(this.users);
}

}
```

In the people component, I have changed the message by the activeForInbox method.

```
export class PeoplesComponent implements OnInit {

  public users : UserModel[]=[];
  public userService : UserService;
  constructor(peopleService : PeopleService,userService : UserService) { 
   this.userService = peopleService;
   this.userService.getUser().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
   this.userService.changeUser();
 }

  activeForInbox(userId: string){
   var user = this.users.find(x=> x.userId==userId);
   user.isActiveInbox = true;
   this.userService.messageSubject$.next(this.users);
   console.log(this.users);
   //this.userService.activeForInbox(userId);
   // console.log(userId);
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

 }
```

I want these changes should be detected in the inbox component.

```
export class InboxPeopleComponent implements OnInit {

 public users : UserModel[]=[];
 public userService: UserService;
 constructor(inboxService : InboxService,userService : UserService) { 

  this.userService = userService;

userService.getUser().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
userService.changeUser();

// setTimeout(() => {
//   userService.getUser().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
//   userService.changeUser();
//   console.log(this.users);

// }, 5000);
 }

showdata(){
   this.userService.getUser().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
  // this.userService.changeUser();
   console.log(this.users);
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.userService.changeUser();
  }

 }
```

When I call activeForInbox method from peoplecompoent, changes are not detected by inboxcompoent